# GMAIL: Magento Order/Invoice Emails Bounce Back

Tags: magento-1.7, email, order-email

Basically, when someone places an order and they are using GMAIL account, such customers do not receive any order confirmation, invoice or tracking information.
72 hrs later I receive bounce back

```
Delay reason: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
[MY SERVER IP ADDRESS] Our system has detected that this message is
suspicious due to the very low reputation of the sending IP address.
To protect our users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has
been temporarily rate limited.
```

Emails get bounce back only for GMAIL accounts.  Hotmail, Yahoo are all fine get delivered. Also, my server IP is not blacklisted anywhere.

However, I am able to send email to GMAILaddresses using webmail application such as roundcube and horder.

Any idea how to fix the issues with default Magento email not being received by GMAIL accounts?

Comment: You could try setting up Google Webmaster Tools, Google Analytics, and maybe even Google Trusted Shop. This may let Google know that you are a real store. I would assume that Google just does not have enough information about your site, or that a lot of people have been marking your email as spam.

Comment: Have all of the mentioned accounts. Its a recent issue, so possibly someone marked messages as spam and now they got flaged. I would be ok if they were placed in spam folder, but in my case they are not delivered at all. I get bouncebacks.

Comment: I also found this https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/C-ItEAaKSo4/73eUpE6kNAAJ which talks about SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records. Maybe you might want to look into these. Google may also be throwing a fit if you send a significant amount of mail or newsletters, which it may interpret as spam.

Comment: Also double check that you are not blacklisted using something like http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I may have discovered something to this problem. Recently, my accounting department started getting bounce backs. When I looked at the list of bounce backs, there were some common themes to them. The terms "INVOICE", "CHECK", "REQUEST", "INV", and various other accounting terms were used in the subject line.
Recently, there have been loads of spam that say things like "your invoice is ready" with a link to bad places. I think that some anti-spam agents have simply said "these are the words that we will flag as spam to keep everyone happy."
The problem is obvious... when someone sends out a legit invoice, it will get caught in this net. SO, I told my accounting dept. to simply not use accounting language in their subject line. We will see how that goes.